# Align contents of col-xs

Tags: html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `col-xs-8` column as follow:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
     <div>Every</div>
     <select id="update-frequency"
              ng-model="retentionSettings.triggers.date.repeat"
              ng-disabled="!retentionSettings.triggers.dateStatus">
          <option value="day">day</option>
          <option value="week">week</option>
          <option value="month">month</option>
      </select>

      <div ng-show="retentionSettings.triggers.date.repeat=='week'">
           <div>on</div>
           <select id="weekDayDropDown" 
                 ng-model="retentionSettings.triggers.date.weekday"
                 ng-disabled="!retentionSettings.triggers.dateStatus">
                 <option ng-repeat="x in weekdaysList()">{{x}}</option>
            </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

The contents of this column with the above snippet pile up vertically like so:

[image]

I'd like to have them horizontally. Im avoiding using more columns inside this one because the spacing wont work for a sentence where the words should be near eachother. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is the divs for "Every" and "on" by default have a `display: block`. You could add custom styling to change the display value to fix this or you could not use div as demonstrated here:

```html
<div class="col-xs-8">
     <span>Every</span>
     <select id="update-frequency"
              ng-model="retentionSettings.triggers.date.repeat"
              ng-disabled="!retentionSettings.triggers.dateStatus">
          <option value="day">day</option>
          <option value="week">week</option>
          <option value="month">month</option>
     </select>

      <span>on</span>
      <select id="weekDayDropDown" 
               ng-model="retentionSettings.triggers.date.weekday"
               ng-disabled="!retentionSettings.triggers.dateStatus">
          <option ng-repeat="x in weekdaysList()">{{x}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct, `<span class="inline">` does seem to do the job for 'every'/'on'. For `<select>`, the dropdown is being show on the same line, but then anything which succeeds it ("on" and `weekDayDropDown`) is show on the next line. Any suggestions?

Comment: @OrangePot I'm not sure I understand the problem. When I run the above code it has "Every <select> on <select>" both spans and selects are on the same line